# Load Custom Address Form in netsuite using suitescript 2.x

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

*There is a requirement to load custom address form and access the form details from the NetSuite custom address form, I need to access the address template in custom address form. Is there any possible way to load the custom form?*

Comment: Please clarify your requirement.  Do you need to load a address record that is on a custom form? Or literally load a custom address form (which is not possible), unless you mean when creating a new address to make sure the custom form is loaded/selected...

Comment: @Martha I need to load custom address form or i need to get all the field ids in that particular custom form

Comment: Dealing with those addresses is notoriously difficult.